# Keyboard Listener from pynput

Tags: python, keyboard

I am trying to import a keyboard listener into my class but keep getting a

```
NameError: name 'on_press' is not defined
```

Here is my code:

```
from pynput import keyboard
class game_code:

    with keyboard.Listener(on_press=on_press) as listener:
        listener.join()

    def check_key_press(self,key):
       try: k = key.char
       except: k = key.name

       if k in ['up', 'down', 'left', 'right']:
          self.key = keys.append(k)
          return True

        else:
          return False
```

Also not 100% sure on how with statements work.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I got it working using the format of their documentation online:

https://pythonhosted.org/pynput/keyboard.html

```
from pynput.keyboard import Key, Listener

def on_press(key):
    #print('{0} pressed'.format(
        #key))
    check_key(key)

def on_release(key):
    #print('{0} release'.format(
       # key))
    if key == Key.esc:
        # Stop listener
        return False

def check_key(key):
    if key in [Key.up, Key.down, Key.left, Key.right]: 
        print('YES')

# Collect events until released
with Listener(
        on_press=on_press,
        on_release=on_release) as listener:
    listener.join()
```

Comment: I pasted the listener into my class code and still getting a NameError. However when running this in a different module outside of a class it works fine. Does it have something to do with using this within a class?

Comment: Runs fine on my end. I'm using it here. Take it out of the class and try it. It's probably because you're not defining on_press like I did above. It needs a definition function