# NameError: name 'Listener' is not defined

Tags: python

```
def on_press(key) :
    print("(0) pressed".format (key) )

def on_release(key) :
    if key == Key.esc:
        return False


with Listener(on_press=on_press, on_Release=on_release) as listener:
    listener.join()
```

Comment: Im a 14 yo kid and I don't know how this site or pycharm goes. I tried to follow this guy (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TbMKwl11itQ&t=57s) but I get this error when I run it: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\Apps\Projects\Keylogger\venv\Keylogger.py", line 9, in <module>
    with Listener(on_press=on_press, on_Release=on_release) as listener:
NameError: name 'Listener' is not defined

Process finished with exit code 1

Comment: did you Import the Listener at the top of the script?

Comment: There is no variable, function, or class with the name `Listener` in this code. Where did you define or import that name?

Comment: I did install pynput. I can't upload a screenshot here so I uploaded it on imgur. https://imgur.com/a/D9BFLOV. Is this the correct way to install pynput?

Comment: Your code is missing the "import" line at the top. See the [dupe](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53179197/669576).

Answer (score 1):

## In short:

You forgot

```
import pypnut
from pynput.keyboard import Key, Listener
```

## Explanation

In your code, Listener has not been defined. What `pynput` does is it defines it for you, so you don't need to write the code yourself (these are called "modules", and are very important to programming). In fact, some modules, like `numpy` or `pickle` use `C` integrated with `python` to do tasks faster or do more complicated communication with the computer.